# Is it possible to serve video content using a proxied url?

Tags: node.js, html, video, proxy

Lets say we have a video that is available at
http://www.example.com/video.mp4

Is it possible to embed this video using another name of link which will be untraceable ?

```
<video src ='http://www.proxyserver.com/video.mp4'/>
```

like Proxied link ?

To be Clear : I don't want to download the video.

Comment: Umm... I suppose it works, because your browser doesn't send any direct request to that link...

Comment: if your requirement is to stop the user downloading the video then it won't work... if they can display the video in the browser then they have a URL that points to 'something' and that something could be saved locally (either right click, 'save video as', or grabbing the URL from the page source or network track and using cURL). To protect it beyond that you would need a DRM solution

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, you should create a http server with node using the `http` librairie, and when you get a request on that server you just have to make the real request on `http://www.example.com/video.mp4` using a request module with streaming support, then you can just `res.pipe(videoStream)` and it should work.

Exemple (not tested but something like this should work of course you can use express/koa/etc instead of http)

```
const http = require('http')

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.path === '/video.mp4') {
    const stream = request.get('http://www.example.com/video.mp4')

    res.end(stream)
  }
}).listen(3000)
```

Comment: This is not great . because the video seek is not possible .